# OpenOPC with Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, opc

I am having some problems in making OpenOPC to work with Python 3.6. The environment I am working in is a Windows 2012 Server. I have installed Matrikon OPC Server to test. I have both Python 2.7 and 3.6 installed through the packages Anaconda 2 and Anaconda 3. In Python 2.7 it is working fine. For Python 3.6 I installed following the instructions in this site https://pypi.org/project/OpenOPC-Python3x/. When I try to creat a open_client to the localhost

```
opc = OpenOPC.open_client('localhost')
```

I receive the following error message:

---

> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Pyro4\message.py",
>   line 152, in from_header raise errors.ProtocolError("invalid data or
>   unsupported protocol version") ProtocolError: invalid data or
>   unsupported protocol version

---

It seems that there is a compatibility problem with the Pyro4 package. Currently it is in the release 4.73. The miminun version requeired by the OpenOPC package is 4.61. I tried to install this version but it didn't work also.

Does any one have seen a similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem. I was using the openOPCService from Python 2.7. After I installed the correct version It start working. At least partially.